# How to do under-sampling with K-fold validation in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm dealing with a highly imbalanced dataset for my project rn, for the simplicity, I will give a simple example here: a dataset has a number of 20 '0's and 80 '1's so the total is 100.

Suppose I have already used `X_train, X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y,stratify=y,random_state=42)` to make a stratified split (X_train.shape is 80 and X_test.shape is 20), so my question is how to achieve **under-sampling** **with K-fold validation in the train dataset at the same time**.

My initial thought is use `from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler` to get 16 '0's and 16 '1's (total is 32) to make equal distributed dataset, and do the K-fold cross-validation on that 32 dataset and discard the rest of 48 in the X_train. Use the model to predict the X_test. So I was wondering if this is correct procedure to deal with.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The question as it stands doesn't include enough information for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RandomUnderSampler method to achieve it. Put random states and ratio value in the arguments and try to see if this works.